Unable to Send Thumbnail with Caption and Description using ReactJS and react-helmet-async in production
I am trying to send metadata (like title, description, and an image thumbnail) for social media sharing using the react-helmet-async library in my ReactJS application. However, the thumbnail image and other meta information are not appearing correctly when I share the URL on social media platforms.
I have set up the MetaTags component to inject Open Graph and Twitter metadata, but the thumbnail image and other metadata are not being displayed as expected.
Here is the relevant code for setting the metadata using react-helmet-async:
Below is MetaTags.jsx
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';

function MetaTags({ title, description, image, url, name }) {
    return (
        <Helmet>
            <title>{title}</title>
            <meta name='description' content={description} />
            {/* Open Graph (OG) Tags */}
            <meta property="og:url" content={url} />
            <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
            <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
            <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
            <meta property="og:image" content={image} />
            {/* Twitter Tags */}
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
            <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
            <meta name="twitter:description" content={description} />
            <meta name="twitter:image" content={image} />
            <meta name="twitter:creator" content={name} />
        </Helmet>
    );
}

export default MetaTags;

Below is Blog Details Page (where meta tags are applied):
import MetaTags from "../Metatags";

const BlogDetails = () => {
    const { slug } = useParams();
    const [blogData, setBlogData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch blog details and set state
    }, [slug]);

    const pageTitle = blogData?.blogTitle || "Latest Blog";
    const pageDescription = blogData?.shortDescription || "Read the latest blog updates.";
    const pageImage = blogData?.image || "default_image_url"; // This should be the thumbnail image URL
    const pageUrl = window.location.href;

    return (
        <>
            <MetaTags
                title={pageTitle}
                description={pageDescription}
                image={pageImage}
                url={pageUrl}
                name="test"
            />
            {/* Blog content and other sections */}
        </>
    );
}

The meta tags are correctly populated in the page source when inspecting the elements in the browser's developer tools, but the thumbnail image, title, and description are not appearing as expected when the URL is shared on social media. 
